# Retorno de Consulta PHP em Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Como faço para obter os valores de consulta PHP em AJAX?

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'listaGabaritosSelecionados.php',
   success: function(url){
     $('.retorno').html(url);
   }
 });
```

**PHP**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "site"); 
$idProduto = 42;
$query = "SELECT * FROM produto where produto_id = '$idProduto'";
$consulta = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $consulta->fetch_assoc()){

    $item = $row['item'];
    $ids = explode(',', $item);
    foreach ($ids as $valores) {

        $selecionaGabaritos = "SELECT * FROM gabaritos where id = '$valores' ";
        $banco = $mysqli->query($selecionaGabaritos);
        while ($resultado = $banco->fetch_assoc()) {
            $url[] = utf8_encode($resultado['url']);
        }
    }
}


json_encode($url);
```

Pois quero que seja enviado um ID do produto para o PHP, ele faz uma consulta no banco em 2 tabelas, se eu executo somente o arquivo PHP ele executa, o problema esta no AJAX para o retorno!

---

RETORNO ARQUIVO.php

```
<pre>array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "urlDoArquivoAI"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "http://www.teste.com.br"
}
</pre>
```

No AJAX fica em BRANCO não me retorna nada!

Comment: Tenta dar um: `echo json_encode($url);` no seu arquivo AJAX.

Comment: Ficando assim?
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {id = prod},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'listaGabaritosSelecionados.php',
    success: function(url){
      //$('.retorno').html(url);
      //console.log(url);
      echo json_encode($url);
    }
  });

Comment: Não, isso ficaria dentro do arquivo AJAX que você chama, no caso no `listaGabaritosSelecionados.php`.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado. Mas ele continua a não retornar nada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você pode enviar o parâmetro (id) diretamente pelo script ajax. utilizando a opção "data".

```
$.ajax({
    url: "listaGabaritosSelecionados.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { id : seuIdAqui }, //{[nome_do_parametro_post]: [valor_do_parametro]}
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // Transforma json em string pra renderizar no html
        $(".retorno").html(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Não esqueça de recuperar este valor no script PHP utilizando o `$_POST`

Uma boa dica é ler a documentação: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

---

Para retornar o valor do script PHP você pode fazer desta forma:

```
echo json_encode($valor_retorno)
```

---

#### Código exemplo (testado)

PHP:

```
<?php

echo json_encode([
    "testando" => "retorno",
    "json" => "de",
    "um" => "script",
    "php" => "!!!!"
]);
```

Javascript:

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "rest.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
               $("#here").html(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Saída: 
>   {"testando":"retorno","json":"de","um":"script","php":"!!!!"}

Comment: Amigão, estou testando com o ID direto na consulta, mas obrigado pela dica, o problema esta em o AJAX me trazer este retorno, ele não consegue me retornar nada!

Comment: já tentou um `echo json_encode($valor)` ?

Comment: Sim estou tentando com o echo json_encode($url); e não me retorna!

Comment: Amigo.. é simples. você já testou dar um console.log() no retorno ??
Você esta tentando printar um objeto javascript no html. não vai ser possível, tenta fazer `$(".retorno").html(JSON.stringify(url))`

Comment: Amigão, por incrível que pareça não funcionou!

Comment: vou postar o código que testei na resposta pra você ver..

Comment: e não funciona ainda! Não me retorna nada!

Comment: Então faz um favor, executa teu script php e cola pra nós o resultado completo. um faz um `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($url); echo "</pre>";` e cola o que retornar pra vermos.

Comment: Este é o retorno diretamente no arquivo.php
<pre>array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "urlDoArquivoAI"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "http://www.teste.com.br"
}
</pre> 
Já o AJAX continua a não retornar nada!

Comment: cola na tua pergunta por favor.. tem certeza que está correto este retorno? Não me parece um json (ou php) válido.

Comment: Respondido lá na pergunta!

Comment: Não faz sentido não funcionar isto. Você esta fazendo um `echo json_encode($url);` ao final do script PHP? Atualiza o código na tua pergunta pra versão atual. Tu tentou copiar meu exemplo e executar?? Vê se funciona.

Comment: Fazendo aqui pelo seu exemplo funcionou! Vou identificar agora no meu qual o erro!

Comment: Incrível como nos meus arquivos não funcionam! O seu script funciona!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83005/discussion-between-israel-merljak-and-cristiano-facirolli).

Answer (score 1):

O erro estava se dando devido ao querer executar o arquivo.php dentro de outra pasta, solucionado com a ajuda do @Israel Merljak

Answer (score 0):

Na ultima linha do seu arquivo `.php` substitui `json_encode($url);` por `print_r($url)` e verifica o resultado. Pois você não está dando nenhuma instrução ao PHP para retornar os dados da consulta.

Comment: tentei com o print_r e não me retorna nada!